# jsf custom converter

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2

I'm new to jsf 2.0 and spring 3.0 , i have a requirement to use custom converter in jsf 2.0.But it is not recognized,when i access my xhtml page it is showing an exception 
"Named object not found" .I had used @FacesConverter annotation for the custom converter and it is using in the h:selectOneMenu.But i'm getting the error.could any one help in this...

```
@FacesConverter("selectItemsConverter")
public class SelectItemsConverter implements Converter {
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {

}
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {

}

}
```

h:selectOne Menu code is as follows:

```
<h:selectOneMenu style="width:100px;height:24px;" rendered ="#{row.edit}" value="#{row.modelo.country}" converter="selectItemsConverter" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['veci.admin.ccaa.pais.empty']}">
<f:selectItems value="#{communityView.countries}" var="con" itemLabel="#{con.nombrePais}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Thank you to all.............

Comment: Please add the `h:selectOneMenu` where you call the converter.

Comment: Hi i update my code with h:selectOneMenu

Answer (score 4):

If you want to call the converter by its converterID you need to change your code as follows:

```
<h:selectOneMenu style="width:100px;height:24px;" 
                 rendered ="#{row.edit}" 
                 value="#{row.modelo.country}" 
                 required="true" 
                 requiredMessage="#{msg['veci.admin.ccaa.pais.empty']}">
    <f:converter converterId="selectItemsConverter"/>
    <f:selectItems .../>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The converter attribute of the `h:selectOneMenu` needs a fully qualified class name such as:

```
<h:inputText
    converter="javax.faces.convert.IntegerConverter" />
```

If you want to give your converter a custom id use the `value` parameter:

```
@FacesConverter(value="selectItemsConverter")
```

Comment: With the code i pasted above is worked with jsf 2.0 ejb and jpa .But it is not working with jsf and spring integration. will i change anything..??

Comment: Do you use the `@FacesConverter` annotation with the `value` attribute? In your server log there must be an exception related to your error. You can post the exception as addition to your answer.